# Rails has_many through has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-and-belongs-to-many, has-many-polymorphs

I am trying to find way to get data from a has_and_belongs_to_many association through a secondary model.  I'll say sorry now as I might not explain this right, so best I just show the associations and what I need to do.  I am using Rails 5.

I have:

Incident Model:

`incident has_and_belongs_to_many :apps`

Apps Model:

`app has_and_belongs_to_many :incidents`

`app belongs_to :service`

Service Model:

`has_many :apps`

What I want to find is for my given service what Incidents its been involved in through the apps that it has, but I only want the unique Incidents.

Is there some way i can do `@service.apps_incidents.unique` and get a list of the unique incidents.

My migrations look like this:

Service Table:

```
class CreateServices < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :services do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Apps Table:

```
class CreateApps < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :apps do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :service, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Incidents Table:

```
class CreateIncidents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :incidents do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

App/Incidents Join Table:

```
class CreateJoinTableAppsIncidents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :apps, :incidents do |t|
      t.index [:incident_id, :app_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uniq_by`

```
class Service
  has_many :apps
  has_many :incidents, through: :apps
end
```

You can then do

```
@my_service.incidents.uniq_by(&:incident_id)
```

Comment: Thanks I knew it had to be simple, over thinking things on a friday.  I did get an error with above:
`NoMethodError (undefined method `uniq_by' for #<Incident::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x0000559ad7a8a8a0>)`

but when I run: 
`@my_service.incidents.distinct.pluck(:incident_id)`

I get the right result

Answer (score 0):

Add `incidents` to your `Service`

```
class Service
  has_many :apps
  has_many :incidents, through: :apps
end
```

Then

```
@service.incidents.uniq
```

OR

```
@service.incidents.distinct
```

This should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Service
  has_many :apps
  has_many :incidents,  -> { distinct }, through: :apps
end
```